# Raid controller question "hardware RAID Array Maximum size: 2.3TB"

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I am looking to get a raid controller for my ubuntu server (used as a media server with plex) I am looking to ger this http://www.sybausa.com/productInfo.php?iid=530 however, I am new to raid, and the sentence "hardware RAID Array Maximum size: 2.3TB"

does this mean it can not take 2.3TB per disk, or it can not take more than 2.3tb in total.

I am looking at using 4 x 2tb disks at RAID 5.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way they have it worded means 2 TiB for the whole array, but this appears to be a SIL fake raid card, which I believe supports arrays larger than that, but only 2 TiB per disk.  If you are looking for a real hardware raid, you should look elsewhere ( i.e. more expensive cards ).  If you don't need to dual boot with Windows and don't care about the slight performance advantage of true hardware raid, then you could use Linux software raid, which does support larger disks, and can be used with the built in SATA ports on your motherboard.

Comment: All i ma interested in data storage of media, no dual booting ect. Just ubuntu server LTS humming away. Wouldn't a linux software raid need the motherboard bios to support raid out of the box? As far as I know my board doesn't hence the need for a PCI card.

Comment: I have no idea what a SIL Fake raid is, however, would formatting the drives as GPT work in linux to have a 6TB (seen as one single drive) using raid 5?

Comment: @Chris, no, which is why it is called *software* raid.  SIL is the company that actually makes the chip that board uses, and the special bios/software needed to perform the raid functions.  With the bios fake raid, you don't partition the individual drives at all, so GPT doesn't enter the picture; the bios utility is limited to 2 TiB per drive.  Of course, you can disable the bios fake raid bits, and just use the controller as a bog standard 4 port SATA controller with normal software raid on top and then you use GPT and can use > 2 TiB disks.